# How to find urls in images

Tags: php, html, image, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract urls from a large number of google search results. Getting them from the source code is proving to be quite challenging as the delimiters are not clear and not all of the urls are in the code. Is there a tool that can extract urls from a certain area of an image? If so that may be a better solution.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How do images contain URLs in certain areas? Can you give some context of what you mean? Is this question about scraping Google Image Search by any chance? What did you try so far?

Comment: Scraping Google **is against Google's ToS**.

Comment: You mean you want to extract the image URLs from the pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this excellent lib: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

```
// Grab the source code
$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all anchors, returns a array of element objects
$ret = $html->find('a');

// Get a attribute ( If the attribute is non-value attribute (eg. checked, selected...), it will returns true or false)
$value = $ret->href;
```

EDit :

All "natural" search urls are in the #res div it seems.. With simplehtmldom find first #res, than all url inside of it. Don't remember exactly the syntax but it must be this way :

```
$ret = $html->find('div[id=res]')->find('a');
```

or maybe

```
$html->find('div[id=res] a');
```

Comment: No exactly. It's a PHP Classe that use native DOM PHP functions but making it simpler to use.

Comment: I want to distinguish between paid search and natural search. Finding all the urls is not a problem, the problem is finding the urls that are paid search and which are natural search. So far I have been trying to work with explode, but the delimiters in google's code are messy. Any suggestions? @CoBaLt2760 @Moshe

Comment: All "natural" search urls are in the #res div it seems.. With simplehtmldom find first #res, than all url inside of it. Don't remember exactly the syntax but it must be this way : $ret = $html->find('div[id=res]')->find('a'); or maybe $html->find('div[id=res] a');

Answer (score 1):

Try using the JSON/Atom Custom Search API instead: http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html. It gives you 100 api calls per day, something you can increase to 10000 per day, if you pay.